# How to input a huge txt using fread() and put it into a stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, stream, fread, stringstream

I am trying to input a huge txt file (approximately 5 MB) into a stringstream, but I face a problem to define fread(). I know, here, I have to use a string to put that string created by fread(). Here is my code, I don't know where is my mistake. I'm eagerly waiting for a solution.

```
FILE *f;

string buffer;
f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fread(buffer, 1, buffer.size(), f);

stringstream s(buffer);
```

Comment: You're reading into an empty string... `buffer.size()` will be 0, *and* [this  doesn't even compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fce9455a90bc9e35)...

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [C++ standard I/O streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)? Also, a `std::string` object can't be used as a pointer to the contained string buffer, so your code won't even compile.

Comment: It sounds very unnecessary to take a detour over `FILE*` and `stringstream` when you could use `std::ifstream`.

Comment: I'm using the C version of libzip (to ensure good performance) to read in json files from encrypted zip files, and my json parser uses stringstreams, so I'm looking for a convenient and efficient way to stringstream-ify a memory buffer that was populated with fread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a good reason to not be using C++ standard I/O streams, here's how you can do it:

```
#include <iostream>

void process_file() {
  std::stringstream s;
  {
    std::ifstream in("input.txt");
    s << in.rdbuf();
  }
  ...
}
```

Then again, you might want to ask yourself why you're putting the file contents into a stringstream, rather than usfing the ifstream directly...

If for some reason you don't want to use C++ I/O streams, you can make it work C-style like this:

```
void process_file() {
  stringstream s;
  // your buffer is going to be allocated on the stack, so you may want to keep it relatively small
  constexpr size_t BUFFER_SIZE = 1024; 
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  FILE *f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  while (fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, f))
  {
    s<<buffer;
  }
  fclose(f);
  ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use read as below , if you fall back on using fread , else c++ STL provides better way to do same thing .

FILE *f;

```
char buffer[1024];
std::stringstream s;
f = fopen("input.txt", "r");
while (fread(buffer, 1, 1024, f))
{
    s<<buffer;
}


std::cout<<s.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not c++, but plain c, in c++ u can:

```
std::fstream f("input.txt", "r");
```

After that u can use `f` just like `stringstream` without any extra code